# How do url is giving response without returning in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
router.delete('/:productId',(req , res,  next) =>{

        res.status(200).json({
            message : "Deleteed product",

        });
    })
```

1)Hi i am new to node.js i came across the following code  I am very much conduced how the  message is being displayed in the postman without we return the object

2)In the same way code is return every where can any one explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.json()` tells Express to convert that object to JSON and send that as the http response.   Responses are sent in Express this way, not by returning objects.

To explain further, `router.delete()` registers a route and a callback to call when that route is matched by an incoming http request.  The callback will be called by the Express framework when an incoming request matches the route specified as the first argument to `route.delete()`.

That callback then has a couple things it can do in response to the incoming http request.  It can either send a response to the http request (thus completing the http request) or it can call `next()` which will tell the Express framework to continue look for other routes that might match the current http request.

In this particular case, `res.json()` sends the http response (completing the http request).  That's how routes in Express work.  `res.send()` sends text, `res.json()` converts into JSON and sends that string.  If you want to send a response for the http request, you can do either one of those.

Express does not expect the callback to `route.delete()` to have a return value of any kind.  Instead, the callback either sends the http response or tells Express to continue routing by call `next()`.  In this particular case, the code is sending the http response with `res.json()`.

Comment: Thanks (i did not mention in the code)
but why are we exporting module.exports = router;  insted of using the file name

Comment: @mdvenkateshnuhk - You have shown no code that does that so I cannot comment on what your code is doing without seeing the actual code.   `module.exports = router;` sounds like it is exporting a router so that some other nodejs module can load this module and get access to the router to use it.  This is a common way of putting routes in another file and then exporting the router so that other code can use it.